# What online resources are there to learn about VxWorks?

Tags: reference, vxworks

What are some of the online resources you have found useful to learn about VxWorks?

Answer (score 3):

[Tornado II/VxWorks FAQ](http://www.xs4all.nl/~borkhuis/vxworks/vxworks.html) is a good source of basic information, related to the 5.x version of VxWorks.

[VxWorks Cookbook](http://www.bluedonkey.org/cgi-bin/twiki/bin/view/Books/VxWorksCookBook) also has some good stuff

[VxWorks Usenet Group](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.vxworks) is good to see the sort of things that stump people

[Collection](http://www.quickembeddedtips.com/vxworks-tutorials-links-howtos) of VxWorks tutorials links (not all of them are live)

This [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=vxworks+manual) brings up a few links to online versions of the reference manuals.

Comment: VxWorks Cookbook (BlueDonkey.org) is gone.